# Send HTTP request as fast as possible

Tags: networking, curl

In order to test my program, I want to send about 50 http requests as fast as possile. Currently I'm using bash script which calls curl & to send each request like

```
curl "http://my.host.com/test.php?param=1" &
curl "http://my.host.com/test.php?param=2" &
curl "http://my.host.com/test.php?param=100" &
```

but it seems not fast enough. I guess since each curl call will establish a tcp connection first, and performance can be improved if the connection is established only once. Is there any other tools to send request effciently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache comes with a program called "ab" for benchmarking. On the net, there are many stress test applications for websites that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP (and also in CURL of course) there is [something really nice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

It takes about 16 seconds to do 1000 regular GETs on google.com, about **63 requests per second**.

Answer (score 3):

Apache JMeter in more than one machine running at the same could be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use bash. Use any other scripting language (Perl, Python, whatever), then create a single connection and pound away on the requests as quickly as possible. For bonus points, launch multiple threads so that you test your program's ability to handle simultaneous connections!

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a good way to [load test apache](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/17950).

From their site:

> Apache JMeter  is open source
>   software, a 100% pure Java desktop
>   application designed to load test
>   functional behavior and measure
>   performance. It was originally
>   designed for testing Web Applications
>   but has since expanded to other test
>   functions.
>
> What can I do with it?
>
> Apache JMeter may be used to test
>   performance both on static and dynamic
>   resources (files, Servlets, Perl
>   scripts, Java Objects, Data Bases and
>   Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can
>   be used to simulate a heavy load on a
>   server, network or object to test its
>   strength or to analyze overall
>   performance under different load
>   types. You can use it to make a
>   graphical analysis of performance or
>   to test your server/script/object
>   behavior under heavy concurrent load.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't perform despite the fact that you background all the downloads is that the OS still has to load curl (from cache but still), create a process for it, parse the parameters, etc.

You need something that can send N requests in parallel without starting new processes.